# How can I call getSupportActionBar() from simple java class

Tags: android

I have to add more code in following class, but I need to separate `handleMenuSearch()` in another class to organize my code. I can't call `getSupportActionBar()` in the separated class. How do I get support ActionBar in another class?

NewsakHome.java

```
package com.newsak;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by Bassem on 8/26/2015.
 */
public class NewsakHome extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolBar;
    private MenuItem searchItem;
    private EditText searchText;
    private boolean isSearchOpened = false;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.newsak_welcome);
        toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar_newsak);


        //  toolBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setSupportActionBar(toolBar);


    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.search_bar_id:
                handleMenuSearch();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_bar_id);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    protected void handleMenuSearch(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if(isSearchOpened) // is cloases
        {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);

            // hide the Keyboard

            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchText.getWindowToken() ,0);

            //set the closed Icon
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                searchItem.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.search_icon_open));
            } else
            {
                searchItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_icon_open));
            }
            isSearchOpened = false;
        }
        else
        {
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); // set our search layout

            searchText = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.search_text_id);
            searchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                        doSearch(view.getText().toString());
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            searchText.requestFocus();

            //open Keyboard
            inputManager.showSoftInput(searchText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

            //set close icon
            //set the closed Icon
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            {
                searchItem.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.search_icon_closed));
            } else
            {
                searchItem.setIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_icon_closed));
            }
            isSearchOpened = true;
        }
    }
    //You’d add this method too, to close the search entry with the backbutton:
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(isSearchOpened)
        {
            handleMenuSearch();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
    private void doSearch(String value) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "your value is :"+value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: tell your new class to extend NewsakHome

Comment: Just adding more code doesn't mean you need to split your existing class.  It would help if you explained what your new classes are and why they need to separate the sample you've already given.

Comment: because this sample will contain more codes later , so I try to get it simple not to be confused  that's it :) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass a reference of `NewsakHome` into your menu function, something like this:

```
// MenuSearchClass.java
public class MenuSearchClass() {
    public static void handleMenuSearch(NewsakHome context) {
        // use 'context' whenever you want to access one of NewsakHome's methods/members
        ActionBar actionBar = context.getSupportActionBar();
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        ...
    }
}
```

Then, pass `this` into `handleMenuSearch()` whenever you call it:

```
// NewsakHome.java
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.search_bar_id:
            // 'this' will become 'context' in handleMenuSearch()
            // handleMenuSearch() is static to make the example easier to read
            MenuSearchClass.handleMenuSearch(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I do agree with @Peter Brittain though. You shouldn't be splitting a class just to make it smaller or more readable. Activity classes usually handle a lot of functionality, so it makes sense that they'd be some of the larger, more complex classes in your project.

Comment: I'm really Thankful for you :) @ Ryan Cole